# Case-insensitive mode in Rosie Pattern Language

Tags: regex, rosie-pattern-language

Is it possible to use case-insensitive mode with rosie pattern language strings?

Comment: Have you tried asking an author via [github issues](https://github.com/jamiejennings/rosie-pattern-language)?

Answer (score 1):

I've [asked](https://github.com/jamiejennings/rosie-pattern-language/issues/62) this question via github issues.

> There is a macro called **ci** that can be used to turn a literal into a
> case-insensitive literal, e.g.
>
> ```
> $ rosie grep '"ibm"' test/resolv.conf
> search ibm.com mylocaldomain.myisp.net example.com
> $ rosie grep '"IBM"' test/resolv.conf
> $ rosie grep 'ci:"IBM"' test/resolv.conf
> search ibm.com mylocaldomain.myisp.net example.com
> $ rosie match 'find:ci:"IBM"' test/resolv.conf
> ibm
> $ rosie match -o line 'find:ci:"IBM"' test/resolv.conf
> search ibm.com mylocaldomain.myisp.net example.com
> ```

Works for 1.0.0-alpha-1 version.